# Understanding the Properties of a Class

Tags: javascript, class, object, ecmascript-6

Why can't i just write gpa instead of this.gpa in my method? I set this.gpa = gpa in my constructor.

```js
class Student {
  constructor(gpa) {
    this.gpa = gpa;
  }

  stringGPA() {
    return "" + this.gpa + "";
  }
}

const student = new Student(3.9);
```

Comment: Before learning js, please learn about programming basics.

Comment: I recommend you go through some introduction tutorials first. Then you should know that "`this.gpa`" and "`gpa`" are different variables in this context.

Comment: @ShioT ok i will im new to constructors and classes so I dont know how they work. The code isnt event mine i got it from freecodecamp

Comment: @Ele can you provide a link to a good website to learn programming basics from?

Comment: you can, if you define your method in the constructor, in which case closure makes the lexical name available to such "own methods".

Answer (score 1):

Because `stringGPA` does not take any arguments, and `gpa` is a local variable in the `constructor` function - therefore, you have to refer to the `gpa` property of the object:

```js
class Student {
  constructor(gpa) {
    this.gpa = gpa;
  }

  stringGPA() {
    return "" + this.gpa + "";
  }
}

const student = new Student(3.9);
console.log(student.stringGPA());
```

Comment: ok thank you for the help. I think I need to learn more about constructors.